# Parametric curves on surfaces in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graphics

Suppose we have

```
x=linspace(-1,1,25);
y=linspace(-1,1,25);
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z = X.^2 - Y.^2;
surf(Z)
```

[image: surfZ]

How does MATLAB calculate the parametric curves (the black lines in the above figure) for obtaining the surface? Are there any explicit formulas to do that? If the parametrization is (u,v) then how to get MATLAB to spit out the

```
u=f(x,y,z)
v=g(x,y,z)
```

functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The black line on the surface is described by three vectors corresponding to x,y and z coordinates. For example, if you wish to extract the line corresponding to `x=x(5)=-0.6667` you need to extract three vectors that are already contained in the meshgrid and Z-array - `X(5,:),Y(5,:),Z(5,:)`:

```
x=linspace(-1,1,25);
y=linspace(-1,1,25);
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z = X.^2 - Y.^2;
hold off
surf(X,Y,Z)
hold on;
plot3(X(5,:),Y(5,:),Z(5,:),'r','LineWidth',5)
axis square
```

[image]

Similarly, if you want to extract the line at `y=y(5)=-0.6667`, then you need: `X(:,5),Y(:,5),Z(:,5)`:

```
x=linspace(-1,1,25);
y=linspace(-1,1,25);
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z = X.^2 - Y.^2;
hold off
surf(X,Y,Z)
hold on;
plot3(X(:,5),Y(:,5),Z(:,5),'r','LineWidth',5)
axis square
```

[image]

Hope that helps

Comment: yes. Thanks. Can you please look at this question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787224/surface-in-matlab-given-3-points?noredirect=1#comment55342560_33787224